# How to save SQL data in cocoa app properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

So basically I'm using the libsqlite3.dlyb to bring SQL functionality to my app. This is all going well I can save load and update e.t.c fine.

The problem is that my app will potentially be dealing with 1000's of objects at any one time, all arranged in NSTableViews and it can take several seconds (around 6 for 1000 of my custom objects) to update to the SQL database. Therefore, if the user quits the Application whilst it's in contact with the database the code gets torn down and I end up with half updated databases and .db-journaled files hanging around and general nastiness.

My question is: how should I go about saving the SQL data? Should I do it all in the applicationWillTerminate: method? I heard apple don't like weighty tasks carried out there. Or do it as soon as an object has been edited? Or what?

I've looked at using an XPCService to do all the SQL side of the app, however am concerned that if I get the service to UPDATE a load of data and then ask it to SELECT before the UPDATE has finished that I will get a clash. Is this the case? Or are XPCServices co-ordinated enough to avoid this?

I'm using Xcode 6 beta on a macbook pro running 10.10. My app is in objective-c and is saving its data in the sandboxed application support folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look into Core Data yet? It's probably better suited for your task instead rolling your own SQLite db.

Comment: Yes I've looked into all that and I agree that CoreData is probably best suited to the task but I want cross platform compatibility and was informed that CoreData doesn't play well with other systems.

Comment: Also I feel that you lose flexibility when you use CoreData.

Comment: I think I probably need to update the db every time a value on one of my objects is changed by the user. Would you agree?

Comment: OK for anyone who's interested. I'm currently managing my objc objects and observing their changes in a manager object which then saves the changed objects to the SQL database at appropriate intervals. I'm given to understand that this is one of the jobs of NSManagedObjectContext in CoreData. Please correct me if I'm making a big error!